# Troubles with preventDefault() still redirect

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. First of all, this is the scenario: I have searcher, with jQuery (ajax) call a php file to respond the search (preventDefault works here), inside the respond, I have a button that calls a lightbox with a question, I have an other two buttons here, one button its from a form and HERE IS where the preventDefault doesn't work. Let's see the code:

Searcher file:

```
<form action="" method="post" name="search_form" id="search_form">
    <input type="text" name="search" id="search" class="search">
</form>
<div class="resultado"></div>
```

1st Function (inside ajax.js):

```
$(function(){
  $('#search').focus();
  $('#search_form').submit(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
  })

   $('#search').keyup(function(){
         var envio = $('#search').val();

         $('.resultado').html('<h3><img src="../../img/load.gif"/> Buscando</h3>')

        $.ajax({
           type: 'POST',
           url: 'php/buscador.php',
           data: ('search='+envio),
           success: function(resp){
                if(resp!=""){
                      $('.resultado').html(resp);
                 }
           }
       })
    })
})
```

The PHP file (see the html comments):

```
    <?php 
    require_once('../conn/conection.php');

    sleep(0.5);

    $search = '';
    if (isset($_POST['search'])){
        $search = $_POST['search'];
    }

    $consulta = "SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE telefono LIKE '%".$search."%' LIMIT 2";
    $resultado = $connect->query($consulta);
    $fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado);
    $total = mysqli_num_rows($resultado);

?>
<?php if ($total>0 && $search!=''){ ?>
    <h3>Resultado:</h3>
    <?php do{?>
    <div class="datos">
        <div class="datos-icon">
            <img src="../../img/deliver_icon.png">
        </div>
        <div class="datos-info">
            <span><?php echo $fila['telefono'];?></span><br/><br/>
            <b>Nombre:</b> <?php echo $fila['nombre'];?><br/>
            <b>Domicilio:</b> <?php echo $fila['domicilio'];?><br/>
            <b>Entre:</b> <?php echo $fila['calle1'];?> y <?php echo $fila['calle2'];?><br/>
            <b>Referencia:</b> <?php echo $fila['ref'];?>
        </div>
        <div class="datos-ver">
            <a href="cliente.php?id=<?php echo $fila['id_cliente'];?>"><button class="b-lista" title="Ver Cliente"><img src="../../img/view_icon.png" width="30px"></button></a>
                             <!--===== HERES THE =====-->
                             <!--===== BUTTON TO =====-->
                             <!--==== THE LIGHTBOX ====-->
                <a href="javascript:pedidoOpen();"><button class="b-lista" title="Hizo Pedido"><img src="../../img/pedido_icon.png" width="30px"></button></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php } while($file=mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado));?>
    <?php }
    elseif($total>0 && $search=='') echo '<h3>Debes ingresar un número de teléfono</h3>';
    else echo '<h3>No se encontró al cliente.</h3><p>Regístralo en las opciones de arriba.</p>';
    ?>
<!--===== HERES THE =====-->
<!--==== THE LIGHTBOX ====-->
        <div class="pedido-modal">
                <div class="pedido-modal-frame">
                    <div class="pedido-modal-info">
                        <h2>Confirmar Pedido</h2>
                        <div id="pedido-modal-respuesta">
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <!--===== HERE NEEDS =====-->
                                    <!--==== THE preventDefault() ====-->
                                    <!--==== LOOK THE 2ND FUNCTION ====--> 
                                        <form method="post">
                                            <input type="hidden" id="cacahuate" name="cacahuate" value="<?php echo $fila['id_cliente']; ?>">
                                            <button type="submit" id="hacer-pedido" class="boton-registro p-arreglo">SÍ</button>
                                        </form>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="javascript:pedidoClose();"><button class="boton-registro remove p-arreglo">NO</button></a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
```

The 2nd Function (inside the same ajax.js in order):

```
$(function(){
       $('#hacer-pedido').on('click', function(e){
         e.preventDefault();
       })
 })
```

At the moment with the 2nd function I'm testing the preventDefault(), It doesn't work. Any Idea? Thanks for your help.

**UPDATE:**

I do a change that works, i know this is not a good practices. Suggestions to improve my code are welcome.

```
<div class="pedido-modal">
<--=== THE CHANGE: ===-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/ajax.js"></script>
    <div class="pedido-modal-frame">
        <div class="pedido-modal-info">
            <h2>Confirmar Pedido</h2>
            <div id="pedido-modal-respuesta">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <form method="post">
                            <input type="hidden" id="cacahuate" name="cacahuate" value="<?php echo $fila['id_cliente']; ?>">
                            <button type="submit" id="hacer-pedido" class="boton-registro p-arreglo">Sí</button>
                        </form>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:pedidoClose();"><button class="boton-registro remove p-arreglo">NO</button></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: is it dynamically created?the element with id `hacer-pedido`. check if you have duplicate id

Comment: @Pekka It's not dynamically created that id.

Comment: **$('#hacer-pedido').on('click', function(e){}** Is capture button click, not capture form submit, form will be submit after click button

Comment: @HoangHieu Thanks. I tried adding and id to the form, for  example: $('#id-form').submit(function(e)){} but still redirect... Any other idea?

Comment: Have you tried `return false` instead of `preventDefault()` ?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
$(function (){
    $('body').on('click', '#hacer-pedido', function (e){
        e.preventDefault();
    })
 });
```

**Explanation:**

You're trying to bind the `click` event to an element that gets added to the page after the DOM completed rendering.  Instead, bind the `click` event to an existing DOM element (preferably the closest parent container - I chose body simply to demonstrate).

**Note:**
You have multiple elements with the id `hacer-pedido` - that is not valid and will cause problems: ids must be unique. Use a class instead to target multiple elements.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but still redirect. Even with the closest parent container. Do you think its possible to call the second functions inside de first one?

Comment: @Christian I think I see your problem - there are multiple `hacer-pedido` ids on the page. An element's **id must be unique**, otherwise the markup is invalid and jQuery will not behave properly as it will only target one element with that id.  See my note above.

Comment: Thanks again. I deleted the "do while" to avoid that. And still redirect.

Comment: @Christian make sure there are no other elements with that same id - do a search and I'm sure you'll find it.  Good luck.

Comment: I see the same id in an other button. I deleted and still redirect. Anyway, thanks for your help.

Comment: It's also possible that there's a JavaScript error on the page that's prevent the code from executing correctly; Have you looked at the console? Do you see any errors?

Comment: I follow (kind a) your first recommendation. So I put the JS route/src inside the modal div and works.